# Font-Lock an Emacs-Lisp Regexp Group

Tags: regex, emacs, syntax-highlighting, font-lock-mode

I'm currently writing a major-mode for Emacs and am trying to figure out how to get syntax highlighting to work. My major-mode is for a lisp-like language that looks like this:

```
[= a 3]
[= [double x] [* x 2]]
[double a]
```

Basically, what I'm trying to do is write a regular expression to match all words preceded by `[` but not the `[` itself to highlight function calls. I've done some googling and have found that emacs does not support regexp look-behind, so how would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the number of the regex group you want to highlight. So, you could construct a regex to capture the `[` plus the following function name and then only highlight the function's name by specifying the first capture group, eg.

```
(defvar my-mode-font-lock-keywords
  '(("\\[\\s-*\\([^\][:space:]]+\\)" (1 font-lock-function-name-face))))

(define-derived-mode my-mode prog-mode "MyMode"
  (setq-local font-lock-defaults '(my-mode-font-lock-keywords)))
```